# Weighted sum of zero-mean random variables

Tags: pr.probability, expectation

Let us say we have two *independent* random variables $X$ and $Y$, with both $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$.

Is it true that for *any* random weight variable $0 \le W \le 1$ (e.g., $W$ dependent on $X$ and $Y$) we have that
$$
E[WX + (1-W)Y] = 0?
$$

Alternatively, what can be the conditions on $X$, $Y$, and $W$ for this to hold?

And if so, does it generalise to $n$ mutually independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ with $E[X_i]=0$, and weight random variables $W_1, W_2, \dotsc, W_n$, $0 \le W_i \le 1$, such that $W_1+W_2+\dotsb+W_n=1$ (where, again, the weights $W_i$ depend on $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$)?

Answer (score 3):

As stated, the answer is no. For example, take $Y$ to be identically 0, $X$ uniformly distributed between -1 and 1, and $W$ to be $(X+1)/2$. Then $E[WX + (1-W)Y] = E[X^2]/2 \neq 0$.